# Android Java popupmenu in onCreate if no SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, oncreate, popupmenu

I am pretty new to JAVA programming and genereally think this language is not very good readable and even harder to write, if you are new to it.

Following issue:

I have an **Activity**.

In **onCreate** I define a **button** 'setlocation' that opens a **popupmenu** with menuitems from a JSON-like string.

```
    setlocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setlocation);
    setlocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, setlocation);
           // Inflate popupMenu programmatically
           try {
               JSONArray txturljsonarr = new JSONArray(getString(R.string.txturljson));
               for (int j = 0; j < txturljsonarr.length(); ++j) {
                   JSONObject txturljsonitem = txturljsonarr.getJSONObject(j);
                   String menuitem = txturljsonitem.getString("menu");
                   popupMenu.getMenu().add(menuitem);
               }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                   try {
                       JSONArray txturljsonarr = new JSONArray(getString(R.string.txturljson));
                       for (int j = 0; j < txturljsonarr.length(); ++j) {
                           JSONObject txturljsonitem = txturljsonarr.getJSONObject(j);
                           String menuitem = txturljsonitem.getString("menu");
                           String chosenitem = (String) menuItem.getTitle();
                           if (menuitem.equals(chosenitem))
                           {
                               query_url_from_txturljson = txturljsonitem.getString("url");
                               title_from_txturljson = txturljsonitem.getString("title");
                           }
                       }
                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   // write title, url to SharedPreferences
                   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appsharedprefs.edit();
                   editor.putString("shpref_url", query_url_from_txturljson);
                   editor.putString("shpref_title", title_from_txturljson);
                   editor.apply();
                   makeJsonArrayRequest();
                   return true;
               }
           });
           // Showing the popup menu
           popupMenu.show();
       }
```

In the **same Activity**, also in **onCreate** I check if SharedPreferences set by the code above are present. If they are not present I would like to **use the popupMenu** defined (the variable is is set for the whole Acitivty: "private PopupMenu popupMenu;") above to set the SharedPreferences.

```
SharedPreferences appsharedprefs = this.getSharedPreferences("appsharedprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);       
shpref_url = appsharedprefs.getString("shpref_url","no URL defined");
    if (shpref_url.equals("no URL defined"))
    {
        popupMenu.show();
    }
```

Unfortunately this leads the app to crash.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.PopupMenu.show()' on a null object reference
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks, Joachim

Comment: can you please post full code of your main activity instead or in addition to this snippets ?, I'm having a hard time understanding where's your shared preferences code you mentioned in the second snippet. I have a hunch about what the problem could be but I want to be sure.

Comment: sorry, can't post the whole acitivity. Linewise the SharedPreferences is above the setlocation definition.

Comment: You created a new popupmenu in onclicklistener, it is not the one that "the variable is is set for the whole Acitivty: "private PopupMenu popupMenu;", so the class member popupmenu is null as it's not initialized.